# How much GPU RAM should be used for 4K display?

Tags: macos, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce, 4k-resolution

I have a macOS Sierra setup with GTX 970 (4GB of VRAM). I also have 4K and FullHD displays connected to it.

When I perform usual tasks, such as browsing, etc (not gaming) I see the following **GPU** memory stats:

```
Total memory: 4.00GiB
Free memory: 483.65MiB
```

Is it okay that it consumes 3.5 GB of VRAM?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple extension of the modern paradigm

> Empty RAM is wasted RAM.

It's far quicker for it to fetch something it already has in RAM than to go back to where it got that data & re-load it.
So, unless it needs the RAM for something new, it will just hang onto what it already has, in case it needs it again.

Comment: The main problem is that remaining 500 mb of VRAM is not enough for such things as some CUDA-based computations :)

Comment: @arts777 Correct me if I am wrong, but didn't the GTX 970 have a memory controller error where it would only utilize 3.5GB of the total 4GB of VRAM?

Comment: @MrPublic I've heard something about that, but not sure if this error present on every GPU. In fact, I had some use cases when there were utilized more than 3.5 GB (for example, the copy-pasted CUDA log from the question is one of these cases).